# CAKEPHP: Using two Models to Show data in one table using one View and one Controller ERROR: Undefined variable: total_hours

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, cakephp

**What I am trying to do is** Getting *fetchdata* function from **Attendence** Model and **fetch** function for **Employee** Model

## My Problems:-

Problem 1
***Notice (8): Undefined variable: total_hours [APP\View\Employees\index.ctp, line 32]***
Problem 2
***The Values are not getting inserted in the same table***

## EmployeesController.php

> ```
> <?php
> class EmployeesController extends AppController {
>
>     public $uses = array('Employee', 'Attendence');
>     public function add()
>     {
>
>
>         if($this->Employee->add($this->request->data)==true){
>             $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
>         }
>
>
>     }
>
>      public function index(){
>         $this->set('employees',$this->Employee->Fetch());
>          $this->set('attendence',$this->Attendence->fetchdata());
>
>     }
>
>
>
> }
> ```

## Attendence.php (MODEL)

> class Attendence extends AppModel {
>
> ```
> function add($data){
>     if (!empty($data)) {
>         $this->create();
>         if($this->save($data)) {
>             return true ;
>
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> function fetchdata() {
>     return $this->find('all', array('conditions' => array('Attendence.date' > '2014-04-23',
>         'AND' => array('Attendences.date' < '2014-04-30')
>            )));
>
>
>           }
> ```
>
> }

## Employee.php (Model)

> class Employee extends AppModel {
>
> ```
> function add($data){
>     if (!empty($data)) {
>         $this->create();
>         if($this->save($data)) {
>             return true ;
>
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> function Fetch() {
>     return $this->find('all', array(
>             'fields' => array('Employee.id', 'Employee.firstname','Employee.lastname','Employee.salary') )
>     );
> } }
> ```

## index.ctp(VIEW attached with EmployeesController)

```
<div class="index">
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Num</th>
    <th>Employee</th>
    <th>Start Date</th>
    <th>End Date</th>
    <th>Salary/Hour</th>
    <th>Total Hour</th>
    <th>Total Salary</th>
    </thead>

<?php
$id = 0;
foreach($employees as $e):?>
 <? $id++ ?>

    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $e{'Employee'}{'id'} ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $e['Employee']['firstname'], $e['Employee']['lastname'] ?></td>
        <td>2014-04-24</td>
        <td>2014-04-29</td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $e['Employee']['salary'] ?></td>'
    </tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>

    <?php foreach ($attendence as $et){
            $ts1 = strtotime($et['Attendence']['in_time']);
            $ts2 = strtotime($et['Attendence']['out_time']);
            $diff = abs($ts1 - $ts2) / 3600;
            $total_hours += number_format($diff,2);
          }
          //Total hours
          echo '<td style="text-align:center">'.$total_hours.'</td>';

          //Total Salary
          echo '<td style="text-align:center">'.$total_hours*$e['Employee']['salary'].'</td>';


          ?>
</table>
</div>

<div class="actions">
    <h3>Actions</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/users/add">New Employee</a></li>
        <li><a href="/user_types">Attendance</a></li>
        <li><a href="/users/add">Salary Calculator</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `The Values are not getting inserted in the same table` There is no code in the question attempting to insert/update anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using/incrementing a variable that isn't initiated yet.

update this line:

```
<?php foreach ($attendence as $et){
```

to:

```
<?php $total_hours = 0; foreach ($attendence as $et){
```

Comment: It removed the error but not showing the Total Hours and Total salaries for each employee... rather showing two values at the end of the table and I suppose they are the total sum.... any help?

Comment: @Neel - the orignal question was about the undefined variable and it seems to be resolved now. As for your other error, it appears to be a separate issue on it's own. Can you show a screenshot of what you are seeing.

Comment: Ofcourse its not a downvote answer.... its the perfecr answer for the first problem... the person who downvoted it should clarify the reason...